# How can I change the <img src> to <data-original> for lazyload wp smilies

Tags: images, filters

I tried to improve my WordPress performance, and already put the content `<img>` with jQuery LazyLoad.

Now, I got some problem in changing the smilies `src`, already set the theme smilies add

Used:

```
add_filter('smilies_src','light_smilies_src',1,10);

function light_smilies_src($img_src,$img,$siteurl) {
    return get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/smilies/'.$img;
}
```

When I added...

```
$img="<img data-original=\"{$file}\" alt=\"{$smile}\" />";
```

it shows...

```
<src="data-original="http://XXX.com/wp-content/themes/Moxx/images/smilies/icon_mad.gif"..
```

How can I change it to something like below?

```
<src="" data-original="http://XXX.com/wp-content/themes/Moxx/images/smilies/icon_mad.gif"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same quotes around the `src` attribute as WordPress uses. So filter the URL like this:

```
add_filter( 'smilies_src', function( $src ) {
    return "' data-original='$src";
});
```

And while I was on it, I noticed the doc block for the function `translate_smiley()` is wrong, so I have written [a small patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25440). :)